# Issues with running Code Igniter on a 5.3 php host

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im making a web app using php / Codeigniter, the clients hosting setup is running 5.3 which i cant change, i went through the docs for Codeigniter and saw that it works on php 5.1.6+.

But will i have to change the code at all, ie using `= array()` instead of `= []` or will Codeigniter be able to intereate my php 5.4 code and allow it to run on a 5.3 hosting platform?

Comment: `array()` or `[]` is up to PHP, CodeIgniter will see an array made in either structure the same. Assuming, the PHP version installed supports it (5.4+) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, They are language constructs, Code igniter has no way to add them internally.

Your code needs to be 5.3 compatible if you wish to run in a 5.3 environment